# Can this Aggregate Lambda expression be converted to a LINQ query?

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have a list of integers summed by an Aggregate method using a Lambda expression:

```
var mylist = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };

var result = mylist.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

As I understand it, a Lambda expression can always be converted to a LINQ query. How would such a LINQ query look for my example?

EDIT: I understand .Sum may be better to add the numbers in my example. But I would really like to know how this Aggregate will look with a LINQ Query instead.

Comment: Just try it to find out!

Comment: It's not fair! You should post comment to my answer, if your "requirements" have been changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already IS a LINQ query, Aggregate is a LINQ operator, i'm assuming what you meant was how it would look like in the LINQ comprehension syntax? The comprehension syntax only has a few built in features (select , where, multiple selects, groupby etc), it doesn't have all operators built in so when you need one of those (such as aggregate) you wrap it around parenthèses and keep going with the regular syntax. Since there is nothing there except aggregate it's not possible to give an example so i'll go from a different query:

```
var mylist = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

var result = mylist
    .Where(item=>item %2 == 0)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);

var ComprehensiveResult = 
    (from item in mylist
     where item % 2 == 0
     select item)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Comprehensive syntax is more of a "LINQ for people coming from SQL introduction", there's nothing you can do in it that you can't do with plain using the operators but the reverse isn't true as not all operators have built in replacements. The only thing that comes to mind where Comprehensive syntax is better (aside from personal taste) is multiple selects to generate a cartesian product which is much harder to maintain in plain method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Aggregate function adds numbers each other. So, the equivalent function is `SUM`:

```
var qry = mylist.Sum(x=>x);
```

or

```
var qry = (from n in mylist select n).Sum();
```

**[EDIT]**

OP has added extra information to the question without  informing me about that.

Yes, it's possible to "convert" `Aggregate` function into linq query, but extension method is needed. See this article: [Cumulating values with LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429176/Cumulating-values-with-LINQ#xx4324335xx)